# Trying to add recent post to static front page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, static, html, posts

I am using a static front page on Word Press, and I want the page to show my most recent post on the bottom of the page.  The problem is, the code is only for one particular post, and I don't know how to tell the computer to get the most recent post and to make it show up correctly.  Here's  a link to my webpage, keep in mind it's nowhere near complete. [Electric Car WordPress Site](http://leifsegen.com/sandbox/livia_t/electric-car/wordpress/)

```
<?php 
                $args = array('name' => '4th');
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>


            <div class="post">

                <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->

                <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>

                <!-- Display the Post's content in a div box. -->

<div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>


    <?php // get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>


</div>
```

Comment: In your $args - remove the name = ....  as that is specifically requesting that post. You probably want to add in your own arguments there to specify exactly what you want. Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query for more info

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

pretty straightforward, just remove any args you don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your arguments array to select one post per page (using the "name" parameter you are currently selecting a specific post with the slug "4th"). Without any further arguments, the most recent post should appear.

$args = array('posts_per_page' => 1 );

For more on WordPress query parameters, check out this page in the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks, now it shows only my most recent post.  Do have any idea about how I can make it look like a normal post?  Right now it's just hyperlink text that shows up on the screen.

Comment: What do you mean by a "normal post"? You can code this to show whatever you want: the featured image, the post title, a post excerpt, the full content etc. It just depends what you want. The code pasted above is calling for the Post Title (as a hyperlink to the post), the post date and author, and content...with the template part commented out (so it won't appear).